# (Matlab for loop) Can parameter be added to be larger at loop?

Tags: matlab

```
for i = 1:72000
    if data(i) > 1000
        beatpoint(i) = 1; 
        i = i + 72;          
    end
end
```

I want that when detecting the value of data is larger than 1000, then the parameter will be additionally added 72. So that it can skip 72 points.

But the result I observe, it seems that it doesn't skip the 72 points when data is larger than 1000.

Can I code this with this way?

Answer (score 2):

This code will not work as you want to. A possible solution is to use while loop, and variable `i` will be increased by one every loop step (as in the for loop), and, if necessary, by 72:

```
i=1;
while i<=72000

    if data(i)>1000
        beatpoint(i)=1; 
        i=i+72;
    end
    i=i+1;
end
```

Try to avoid changing your for loop iterator inside the loop.

Edit:  It should be `i<=72000` in the for loop.
Edit #2: Better to increment at the end, as long as can get out of bound error

Comment: Nice you beat me by a few seconds haha. 2 little things though: 1) Shouldn't your `while` condition be `<= 72000`? 2) Shouldn't the `i = i+1` be after the ``if` statement? Otherwise some data may be skipped since you do `i = i+1` and then `i = i+72`, so basically `i = i+73`?

Comment: @Benoit_11: When initializing i with zero, this seems to be fine.

Comment: I agree about 1), my fault (fixed). I don't agree about  2). You need to start looping with `i=1`. This is what is written in my code.

Comment: Now you get a index out of bound, i is 72000 at the beginning of last iteration and then incremented by 1